# Why is click event binding twice after adding jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slidetoggle, page-init, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I was working on an MVC web project that was using `jquery` to toggle a `div` upon the click of an `a` tag. It was working fine. I then added `jquery.mobile` to the project and now all the click events are triggering twice. I spit out the handlers for the click event to the console and saw that it was bound three times, but really only triggers twice. My guess is that both `jquery` and `jquery.mobile` are both binding and firing.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dashboard - Environmental Monitoring System</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="featured" id="feature-header">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <hgroup class="title">
                    <h1>Dashboard.</h1><br />
                    <h2>Display the status of all the sensors in the system.</h2>
                </hgroup>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">                

            <div>
                <a href="#"style="position:relative;left: 6px;top:-6px;text-decoration:none;background-color:none;" id="feature-header-button"><span class="icon-plus" style="display:none;" id="feature-header-plus">&#9660;</span><span class="icon-minus" id="feature-header-minus">&#9650;</span></a>
                <script>
                    $("#feature-header-button").click(function () {
                        $("#feature-header").slideToggle("slow");
                        $("#feature-header-plus").toggle();
                        $("#feature-header-minus").toggle();
                    });
                </script>
                <div style="margin-left:75px;">
                    Content.
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will probably move to using `collapsible` with `jquery.mobile` which is working fine, but I want to understand this problem to prevent it from causes problems in the future. I have read tons of posts about using `pageinit` and double-binding and bubbling, etc, but still could not diagnose and fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely sounds like both are binding and firing. You should put in checks to only load in the required jQuery based on the user's browser.

Comment: [Seems fine](http://jsbin.com/iqucob/1/edit), do you have some other code running on the page?

Comment: No other code running on the page. There is some `CSS`, but that shouldn't have any effect. The code worked great with just `jquery` but started firing twice after adding `jquery.mobile`. My main test browser is Chrome but it happens in IE as well. Wonder what the difference would be between local and the version hosted by `jsbin`?

Comment: Did you take a look at the jsbin I linked to, I didn't examine the handlers but it seems to be only firing once. I basically just copied your code minus the *modernizr* script.

Comment: Yes, I saw it working correctly. Could `modernizr` be causing the problem?

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle as well with the scripts linked to the latest versions. It works fine. Is there a problem with `jquery 1.8.2` versus `1.9.1`? Or between `jquery.mobile 1.3.2` and `1.3.1`?

Comment: Not sure, is there a reason why you re using an older version of jQuery and JQM? At any rate try testing all three scenarios locally.

Comment: I was using those versions because that is the latest `NuGet` package versions for VS for Web 2012. Not sure how often those get updated, but I manually changed the bundle configs to included the latest versions and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I changed to link in the newest versions of both `jquery` and `jquery.mobile` and the problem disappeared. Not sure what the conflict was but `jquery` version 1.10.2 and `jquery.mobile` version 1.3.2 are much happier together. Now to get the new version to be automatically included in the MVC bundles.

Thanks for the comments, that helped me troubleshoot and provide a sanity check.